# Parsing the domain, email and the name out of message.getFrom()

Tags: google-apps-script

I am kind of new to Google Apps Scripts and wonder about the correct syntax to get the following data structure back from the message.getFrom() field:

"@domain email-address name"

as a bonus the same from the message.getTo(). I know that the To field can contain more recipients, so I would like to have only the first one parsed. Also in the format

"@domain email-address name"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the domain is: message.getFrom().split('@')[1].replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+$/,'')

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will do it.

```
function myMessages(){
  var msg=GmailApp.getMessageById(id);
  var fA=msg.getFrom().split('@');
  var msgObj={fromname:fA[0],fromdomain:fA[1],toA:[]};
  var tA=msg.getTo().split(',');
  for(var i=0;i<tA.length;i++){
    var t=tA[i].split('@');
    msgObj.toA.push({name:t[0],domain:t[1]});
  }
  return msgObj;
}
```